# Validar campos JtextField

Tags: java, java-swing, jtextfield

esta funcion valida campos y muestra mediante un joptionPane cual es el campo que hay que corregir en caso de que este mal, mi problema es que pienso que de esta manera se esta incumpliendo la norma de que una función debe hacer una sola cosa ya que esta validando y mostrando un mensaje a la vez.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Esta validación se hace previo al registro de un producto y quiero que siempre que haya un campo incorrecto muestre un mensaje que diga cual es el campo que hay que corregir.

```
    public boolean validarProducto() {
        if (txtNombre.getText().equals("") || txtPrecioLista.getText().equals("") || txtStock.getText().equals("") || cmbCategoria.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe completar todos los campos");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioLista.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese correctamente el precio");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(txtStock.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese correctamente el stock");
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Primero que nada, tienes un error de lógica en el primer `if`, puesto que si lo que quieres que salte el aviso cuando cualquiera de los campos están vacíos, debes usar ORs, no ANDs. Y en cuanto a tu duda... no veo necesidad de separar más la lógica, puesto que necesitarías duplicar las comprobaciones. Si el código para mostrar el mensaje fuese más complejo pues vale, pero en este caso, una simple llamada a JOptionPane... no lo veo muy *sucio*.

Comment: Arroja una excepción o devuelve una lista de errores, así quien invoque puede decidir qué hacer, por ejemplo mostrar un diálogo.